# Film: Creatures taking good looking female forms to end up falling in love with 'husbands'

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I'm trying to find a film and all I can remember are some details and the ending. Here's what I remember:

- Creatures had taken human form

  - Good looking females if I remember right
  - In reality they were like Jabba The Hut – smiley and horrible
- They fell in love with the husbands and wanted to stay
- I think they did people's heads to make themselves look human
- I think it's an 80s movie

Comment: They _did_ people's heads? What does that mean?

Comment: My first thought when i read that was "My Stepmother is an alien", but to many differences to your description

Comment: Being all _smiley_ doesn't sound so bad.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like ["First Anniversary"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Anniversary_(The_Outer_Limits)) an episode of the new *The Outer Limits* second season. It is a 90s TV show not an 80s movie.

> Norman Glass celebrates his first wedding anniversary with his beautiful and talented wife, Ady. Norman's best friend, Dennis, also has a beautiful wife, Barbara. However, over the next few days, both relationships unravel rather quickly. First, Dennis walks out on Barbara; Norman goes to talk to Dennis in a city park and is frightened by what he finds. Dennis, clearly unhinged and paranoid, claims that Barbara is not what she seems, and that she is an alien creature who can change appearance (through influencing people's thoughts). A strange woman approaches Dennis and claims to be Barbara, begging him to take her back. Norman doesn't recognize her, but Dennis does - whereupon he runs into traffic and is killed.
>
> Later, after Dennis' funeral, Norman experiences the same effects: he begins to feel repulsed whenever he touches, smells or tastes his lovely wife. Ady attempts to bluff her way out of the situation but is forced to admit the truth: she and Barbara are aliens whose ship crash-landed on Earth some time ago. They are repulsive creatures in their natural form (apparently, of aquatic origin), but since they are stranded on Earth with no way to leave, they decided to try to blend in and live out the rest of their lives as human women. Unfortunately, their ability to trick someone's senses wears off, as the victim grows a resistance, after a year or so. Norman becomes unhinged at this knowledge and ultimately suffers a mental breakdown when he finally sees Ady's true form. He is taken away by paramedics. Later, Ady is standing in a park where she changes her appearance and starts a flirtatious conversation with a passing jogger.

I thought there was an English version on YouTube but this is what I can find:

Comment: Cheers it was that I thought it was 80s just remembered a few things will have to watch it thanks for the answer